# async/await and service updates

Tags: angular

Small Async/Await on Service question. I think that my problem is zone related but I have no clue on how to solve it.

- I have an async/await call to retreive data from an API
- the get and list of the data is done in a parent
- one of the children component is calling the service to update the data (await for PUT, then await for the new GET to update the array of the service);
- problem : the view does not understand that data has changed.

I have simplified the example without the children/parent stuff.
Clean Example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fz6y3f
In the example, how can I make the list to show "123"

Comment: Observables are a good method

Comment: Can you show this on my stackblitz  ?

Comment: Here's a working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-erm3ur

Comment: Thanks I didn't knew about this next function of subscribe (example their : https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/06/21/angular-8-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject)

Comment: @IMarty, in general to acall an API you use HttpClient, see the docs https://angular.io/guide/http and you needn't use next or Subject, httpClient.get and httpClient.post return an Observable, you only need subscribe to this

Comment: @Eliseo, I use an HttpClient in me code, the question was related to async/await not reloading the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `BahaviorSubject` from `RxJS`.

Here is the example I wrote based on your code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fechcc

#### Reference:

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject

Comment: Please explain here _what_ and _why_ you changed.